# GitKraken and SourceTree, code privacy?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, privacy, gitkraken

Just for my curiosity, when I use these tool only to sync with repo in private network.

Is my code privacy protected, although GitKraken asks for GitHub login.

Thanks,

Comment: I prefer not to use GUI-based git client such as GitKraken for Large-Scale or Private projects. Except using Github Desktop and Github as the cloud repository...

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a bit late, but if someone else stumbles upon this, I might as well give some advice. Note: I am assuming Windows as OS.

There are two main things regarding privacy in this case:

1. Access to code which is associated with your GitHub account
2. Access to your local (cloned) code

SourceTree will use some key you provide via Pageant to clone, pull, push, etc. from your remote repository. You decide which key you use, e.g., if using a deploy key for some repository it will only be able to "interact" with this repository.

For GitKraken it is basically the same when you use a GitKraken account. If you use your Github account to sign in or you want to use the Glo feature, GitKraken asks for **full admin access** as well as read/write permissions on **all** public **and private** repositories.

With that being said, both naturally need to access at least the repository with which you want to work and could, in theory, transfer your code from this repository to a third party (or themselves).

TL;DR

There is no real (as in proven) privacy for your code when using a git client

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes perfect sense.